# Ignoring invalid documents inside a JSONL file

Tags: python, json

I have a file which has one JSON document per line; however, some of these documents are malformed and can't be parsed correctly.

My current code is as follows:

```
def load_tweets(file):
    with open(file, 'r', encoding="UTF-8") as f:
        tweets = (json.loads(line) for i, line in enumerate(f.readlines()))
    return tweets
```

... and then i'm looping in tweets to gather fields. 
I know that in some fields there is double quotes or other nasty characters. I tried .... 1) manually search for lines with problems but the files are enormous 2) a try catch structure in the loop but the error comes when trying to start the loop :

```
for myfile in myfiles : 
    tweets = load_tweets(myfile)
    for t in tweets:
        print (t['id'], "\n")
        try:
            #print (t['id'])
            data['id'].append(t['id'])
(...)
```

3) decoding/encoding  but nothing works.

```
JSONDecodeError: Expecting ':' delimiter: line 1 column 5717 (char 5716)
```

I'm looking for a way to simply skip the line or drop lines when there is malformed JSON. I would love to keep it all but I'm ok to drop them.

I'm using Python 3.4. 
All your help would be appreciated! :)

My code is adapted from [here](https://galeascience.wordpress.com/2016/06/23/loading-tweets-into-a-pandas-dataframe-using-generators/)

Comment: Can you show a piece of your json file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def load_tweets(file):
    with open(file, 'r', encoding="UTF-8") as f:
        for line in f:
            try:
                yield json.loads(line)
            except JSONDecodeError:
                pass
```

Then the rest of the code can be the same.

Comment: Hi Alex,You just made my day ! For others who may have this issue, I had to import this : from json.decoder import JSONDecodeError . Thank you so much !!!